# DataTable not being bound to DataContext of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, datacontext

I have a `DataGrid`, follow the XAML :

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=propCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectProp, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Margin="-1,159,0,0" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" 
              AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="True" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False"  
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
              AlternatingRowBackground="{x:Null}" 
              SelectionChanged="dgProprietarios_SelectionChanged"
              AlternationCount="0"
              Height="200" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Name="dgProprietarios" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="645" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                 <...Columns...>
    </DataGrid>
```

On my **Window_Loaded** I do the following :

```
dgProprietarios.DataContext = new ProprietariosViewModel(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

My **ProprietariosViewModel** is the following :

```
public CollectionProprietarios propCollection { get; set; }

public ProprietariosViewModel(Dictionary<string, string> Where)
{
    propCollection = new CollectionProprietarios(Where);
}
```

The **CollectionProprietarios** class inherits **ObservableCollection** and have the following code :

```
    public CollectionProprietarios(Dictionary<string, string> Where)
    {
        Add(new Dados(Where));
    }

    public new void Add(Dados dados)
    {
        base.Add(dados);
    }
```

The class **Dados** have the following code :

```
public DataTable ProprietariosRetorno { get; private set; }

public Dados(Dictionary<string, string> Where)
{

    var ado = new ADO();
    ProprietariosRetorno = ado.RetornaSelect(MontaQuery(Where));

}
```

The function **MontaQuery** just creates a string that contains a SELECT clause and **RetornaSelect** executes this Query.

The class **ADO**, when instanciated just creates the database and the table if it doesn't exist.

The problem is, all of that is working. While debugging, I can retrieve the value inside the DataContext and it contains the DataTable with values. But for some reason, it doesn't appear on the DataGrid when the program is running.

So the question is, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: On `public DataTable ProprietariosRetorno { get; private set; }` I already tried removing the private set and replace it with set. No luck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
dgProprietarios.DataContext = new ProprietariosViewModel(new Dictionary<string, string>());
dgProprietarios.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: Due to your code - your collection propCollection contains only one element of type Dados. This element contains DataTable ProprietariosRetorno that exactly holds data. So you can try to use next code in your XAML: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=propCollection[0].ProprietariosRetorno}"`.